# Door pulls on closet worn through

Tags: closet, knobs

Just got a house and the handle insert for one of the closet folding doors is completely worn through. Would rather not replace the door. Any suggestions for a fix?

[image: Door front]

[image: Door back]

Comment: I assume the door is hollow?

Comment: Does the thread extend beyond the back of the door, and if so, by how much? Was there hardware on the back side that's not in your picture? I would expect so, as that is a machine threads and not a coarse wood threads on the handle.

Answer (score 3):

A [Combo machine screw](https://www.homedepot.com/p/8-32-x-2-in-Combo-Truss-Head-Zinc-Plated-Machine-Screw-8-Pack-802434/204275052?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK-71700000109986253-58700008375337160-92700076237673158&gclid=CjwKCAjw38SoBhB6EiwA8EQVLvsN1xcoRMYnSpbKoGIU7iZcSYSqH5jkgTY7MtKGa71_lovfp-g0YhoCutIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) long enough to go through the door plus 1/4 inch.

Then use a [Fender Washer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KQJM96C) with the screw through the back side of the door.

If that is pulled through the door, there is abuse going on.